# How to get a String value in an Object from a List?

Tags: java, android, string

I want to get a String value from an Object that consists of an `ImageView` and two `TextView` in my List by clicking on that specific Object. But the problem is, I cannot get the String that I want.

The toast message should show the value of second `TextView` but it shows whatever it likes.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:onClick="chitChat" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    tools:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/uidTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If you have any other suggestion that helps me to get any Object specific value from clicked Object, I would like to hear that.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
public void chitChat(View view) {

    TextView otherUid = findViewById(R.id.uidTextView);
    String othersUid = otherUid.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(PartyActivity.this, othersUid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    if (user != null && user.isEmailVerified()) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(PartyActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);

        myIntent.putExtra("Other Uid", othersUid);

        PartyActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: "...but it shows whatever it likes." what is that exactly?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I mean It doesn't show the exact String value that displays in the <b>TextView</b>. Instead, it shows other Object's value in the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below line

```
TextView otherUid = findViewById(R.id.uidTextView);
```

to:

```
TextView otherUid = view.findViewById(R.id.uidTextView);
```

It should work

Comment: Glad you liked.

Answer (score 0):

...
Hi Sam,
You need to set the text of the second TextView before getting it.
You can do this adding android:text to the second textview in the xml to have static text (the default value).
To have dynamic text into your second textview just set the text when you are creating the element of the List.
Hope this help.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer but of course I set a value in it. I just didn't show that part of the code. It's my bad. Anyways thanks for the response.